# Checkbox in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have simple components which renders comments

```
interface ICommentProps {
  createdAt: string;
  text: string;
  author: IUser;
  replies: IComment[];
  commentRating: number;
}

const Reply: FunctionComponent<ICommentProps> = ({ author, createdAt, text, replies, commentRating }) => (
  <div className={styles.comment}>
    <AdvancedComment createdAt={createdAt} text={text} author={author} commentRating={commentRating} />
    <div className="comments">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      {replies.map(comment => (
        <Reply
          replies={comment.comments}
          author={comment.author}
          createdAt={comment.createdAt}
          text={comment.text}
          commentRating={comment.rating}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Reply;
```

And I want that when I click on the checkbox the code below stopped working:

```
{replies.map(comment => (
        <Reply
          replies={comment.comments}
          author={comment.author}
          createdAt={comment.createdAt}
          text={comment.text}
          commentRating={comment.rating}
        />
      ))}
```

My idea is that when you click on the checkbox, child comments will disappear.
At first I tried to make animation, but unfortunately it didn't work out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vadim!
You can use `useState` [hook](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and make a disabled for your target component

```
interface ICommentProps {
  createdAt: string;
  text: string;
  author: IUser;
  replies: IComment[];
  commentRating: number;
}

const Reply: FunctionComponent<ICommentProps> = ({ author, createdAt, text, replies, commentRating }) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const onChange = useCallback((e) => {
    setDisabled(e.target.checked); // something like this
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className={styles.comment}>
      <AdvancedComment createdAt={createdAt} text={text} author={author} commentRating={commentRating} />
      <div className="comments">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={disabled} onChange={onChange} />
        {replies.map(comment => (
          <ReplyItem
            disabled={disabled} // <- here
            replies={comment.comments}
            author={comment.author}
            createdAt={comment.createdAt}
            text={comment.text}
            commentRating={comment.rating}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Reply;
```

And animation you should make inside a ReplyItem component